# Encountering an exception when I use JArray.Parse

Tags: c#, json, http, string-parsing

I need to make multiple HTTP requests to this URL and I use JArray.Parse to deserialize. The first 2 times I call my HTTP method, it works fine and parses fine and I am able to get my data, but the 3rd time I call the method, it throws me an exception.

I have provided the code which I have used. Can anybody tell me whats going on?

```
   public static string GETActionInfo(int action_input)
        {
            string getDevicesURL = "someURL";
            string action_id = "", device_id = "",strname="";
            int value=0;
            JArray parsedArray=null;
            HttpsClientResponse response=null;
            try
            {
              response = crestronGetHttp(getDevicesURL); //Makes the HTTP call
              if (response.Code != 200) 
              {
                  CrestronConsole.PrintLine(response.Code);
                   return response.Code.ToString();
              }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                CrestronConsole.PrintLine("crestronGetHttp()-->"+e.Message);
            }
                string jsonData="";

                using (Stream stream = response.ContentStream)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            CrestronConsole.PrintLine("ReadToEnd Exception" + e.Message + "_" + e.StackTrace);
                        }
                        string receivedData = jsonData;
                        try
                        {

                            parsedArray = JArray.Parse(receivedData);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            CrestronConsole.PrintLine("JArray Parsing 
    Exception" + e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace);
                        }
               CrestronConsole.PrintLine("Parsed Array" + parsedArray);
         try
         {
         foreach (JObject ob in parsedArray.Children<JObject>())
             {

                   var name = (string)ob["name"];
                   if (name == "My ecobee")
                   {
                       device_id = (string)ob["_id"];
                       var json = (JArray)ob["actions"];

                    }
               }
          }
       catch (Exception e)
             {
             CrestronConsole.PrintLine(" For block--->" + e.Message + "-----" + e.StackTrace);
             }
       }
     }
  }
```

The funny thing is that, when I add a print statement to print the parsed array content and call this method, it works just fine. But when I comment out the print statement, it fails on the third call. I was thinking maybe it has something to do with a delay(since it takes sometime to print all the content of the parsed array). I tried adding a sleep statement to check it out but it dint work.

The exception it throws me is

```
 JArray Parsing Exception-->Unterminated string. Expected
    delimiter: ". Line 1, position 34779.______   at 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote)
    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseProperty(Char firstChar)
    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseObject(Char currentChar)
    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadContentFrom(JsonReader r)
    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Load(JsonReader reader)
    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(String json)
    at yonomi_one_test_one.ControlSystem.GETActionInfo(Int32 action_input)
    at yonomi_one_test_one.ControlSystem.ecoDec(String args)
    at Crestron.SimplSharpProInternal.SimplSharpProManager.f()

 For block--->NullReferenceException-----   at yonomi_one_test_one.ControlSystem.GETActionInfo(Int32 action_input)
   at yonomi_one_test_one.ControlSystem.ecoDec(String args)
```

Comment: The error is pretty explicit; there's a missing quote in the JSON string, at position 34779 (or at least, that's when the parser gave up and stopped looking for the quote). Use JSON Lint or some other tool to make sure the JSON you're getting is valid. If not, talk to the developers of the application sending the data.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Like I said, the first 2 times I call this method, it works fine. I even tried printing the entire contents of the JSON file and it was just fine. Its the third call which is messing it up.